# How to find all data in DB using Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have following classes

```
@Entity
@Table(name="prm_user_permission")
public class UserPermission {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="prm_permission_id")
private Integer permissionId;

@Column(name="prm_permission_name")
private String permissionName;

@Column(name="prm_short_description")
private String shortDescription;

@Column(name="prm_description")
private String description;

@Column(name="prm_url")
private String permissionUrl;

@Column(name="prm_control")
private String control;

@Column(name="prm_create_user")
private Integer creatUser;

@Column(name="prm_parent_id")
private Integer parentId;

@Column(name="prm_system_id")
private Integer systemId;

 // Getter and Setter
```

And my code is

```
public List<UserPermission> findAllBySystemId(int systemId) {
    List<UserPermission> userPermission =    criteria().setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
            .add(eq("UserPermission.systemId", systemId).list();
    return userPermission;
}
```

Now i want to get all data from this (UserPermission) table by "systemId".If i pass systemId=1 then it should give all data where the column is '1'.
what is wrong in my code?  while running it shows error like

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: UserPermission of:  
com.kgfsl.collections.core.security.models.UserPermission
```

Plz anybody help

Comment: don't write "UserPermission.systemId". Only write "systemId"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do the `criteria()` method returns?

And, try with `systemId` directly (eg: remove the `UserPermission.`)

Comment: Thank u all for your explanations

Comment: I removed UserPermission in ...add(eq("UserPermission.systemId", systemId).list(); I juz give ...add(eq("systemId",systemId).list(); Finally its working

Answer (score 0):

Try with `Restrictions.eq()`

```
public List<UserPermission> findAllBySystemId(int systemId) {
    List<UserPermission> userPermission = criteria().setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY) 
                                .add(Restrictions.eq("systemId", systemId)).list();
    return userPermission;
}
```

Assuming that your `criteria()` method would be,

```
session.createCriteria(UserPermission.class)
```